# TV series with some sort of whale / tsunami story element

Tags: story-identification, tv

This is a television series which I saw around 5 years ago, probably shown on the Sky network in Europe. From the effects and so on I wouldn't say it was much older than that. I only caught snatches of it when I happened to be using the gym at the time it was on, because it was sometimes on one the screens there.

The only plot points I can remember is that it involved whales or whale-like creatures to some extent, and from time to time they would get together (possibly because they were annoyed) and cause huge waves to assault fishing towns and villages nearby.

Comment: Normally, searching with the snippets you mentioned turns up results in Google but I'm actually having difficulty searching what you want. I do remember a Star Trek Movie though: Star Trek IV: The Voyage Home. You question title made me search it but upon reading the question, you seem to be looking for something else.

Comment: Thanks, no I'd recognise Star Trek ... this was either a made for TV movie or miniseries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It wasn't by any chance Surface, was it? It doesn't fit your description exactly, but it aired about 6 years ago, and dealt with weird creatures coming out of the ocean, so it's possible that that's what you're thinking of.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_%28TV_series%29